# How I enable dragging only for single line in a Chart.js multiline graph?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a requirement to show 2 line graphs in a single chart. One line graph should be dragable and other one shouldn't be dragable. I was able to enable dragging for both lines, but not sure how to enable it just for one line.

```
var scatterChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type : 'line',
                    data : {
                        labels: labels,
                        datasets : [ {
                            label : 'Scatter Dataset 1',
                            showLine : true,
                            fill: false,
                            data : dp1
                        },
                        {
                            label : 'Scatter Dataset 2',
                            showLine : true,
                            fill: false,
                            data : dp2
                        }]
                    },
                    options : {
                        maintainAspectRatio: false,
                        dragData : true,
                        dragX : false,
                    }
                });
                scatterChart.render();
```